# How to grep specific dates from a html file

Tags: html, shell, grep

I have an HTML file that has a number of dates in this format dd/mm/yy spread all over it. I was looking for a way to retrieve specific dates from it.

input:

```
Released: 08/08/2019</td>
<td>06/26/2019</td>
Released: 03/09/2019</td>
<td>14/29/2019</td>
```

I found a way to retrieve all dates from the file:

```
grep -o "[0-9]\{2\}/[0-9]\{2\}/[0-9]\{4\}"
```

output:

```
08/08/2019
06/26/2019
03/09/2019
14/29/2019
```

However, I need to filter these dates and pick only those that have this format:

```
<td>dd/mm/yyyy</td>
```

So from the above input, I need this output:

```
06/26/2019
14/29/2019
```

Comment: `grep -Po '<td>\K[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}'`

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Hold on: Neither of those two represents a date in the specified format! It's like the 31st of February, those months don't exist. In either case, just read the manual: You can pipe the file into `grep` and tell it to exclude everything that matches a certain pattern. That said, HTML can have linebreaks in various locations, perhaps what you want is a tool that is capable of understanding HTML (or perhaps XML if that's what it is).

Comment: @oguzismail this is just what I was looking for

Comment: `dd/mm/yyyy`  how do you get month `26` and `29`?  How do you see if `02/03/2019`  is `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always recommend using an HTML/XML parser. If this is not possible try GNU grep and a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE):

```
grep -Po '(?<=<td>)[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}(?=</td>)' file
```

Output:

```
06/26/2019
14/29/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

This `gnu awk` may do?

```
awk -F"</?td>" '/^<td>/{print $2}' file
06/26/2019
14/29/2019
```